# HTML5 Audio does not play using source tag, but does using src=

Tags: android, html, html5-audio

I hit an odd issue on some Android devices, specifically OnePlus.

If I format the Audio tag with src= attribute on the audio tag itself the player works (#1). if I am format it according to HTML5 standards using the source element it does not play.

In both cases this works using a browser (Chrome) on Windows.

```
//#1 WORKS - No Source tag but src attribute on audio tag, no type specified
<audio 
    id="rs-player1"     
    src="2241_carnaval-op9-no12-chopin-schimmel.mp3">
</audio>

//#2 DOES NOT WORK (on some android devices) (has source tag with src attribute)
<audio 
    id="rs-player1"> 
    //Source Tag.... 
    <source src="241_carnaval-op9-no12-chopin-schimmel.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: The first example validates as HTML5 according to the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Looks like a typo question: In #2 opening `audio` tag hasn't enclosed with `>`

Comment: hindmost, you are correct, that was a typo in the post, it was correct in the code.

Comment: Why did you use `javascript` tag? Your code has no javascript at all.

Comment: I was concerned that the first tag that has audio and not Source Tag was not valid for HTML5, but Mozzila shows both are valid. The first one is just a basic tag. I am only hitting the issue of using the SOURCE tag on the Android OnePlus device. Every other one I tested is fine with either syntax.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 0):

Have you really tried this way:

```html
<audio  autoplay> 
    <source src="wav/myfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: jmmontero, I had it like that originally but it did not work.  I am going to try just the basic syntax I mentioned on my post reply to see if that will work.